# Dropwizard + Guice Bundle getting Application Configuration in the Module

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard

For the general setup I was following this [tutorial](http://www.codingricky.com/dropwizard-and-guice-integration/). Now, in my guice module I would like to pass construct different Singletons based on the server configuration. The problem is that I can not get the configuration here. How could I achieve this?

```
public class ServerModule implements Module {  
    @Override
    public void configure(Binder binder) {
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public AnInterface provideSingleton() {
        return myServerConfiguration.isSomething() 
               ? new SomeObject() : new SomeOtherObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you read the tutorial carefully again, you will see how they are doing exactly this: by letting guice inject the configuration into the provides method.

Example copied from given link:

```
@Provides
@Named("message")
public String provideMessage(ServerConfiguration serverConfiguration) {
    return serverConfiguration.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: But this seems not to work with singletons: 1) The dropwizard environment has not yet been set. This is likely caused by trying to access the dropwizard environment during the bootstrap phase.

Comment: That is correct. DW complains about the Environment not yet set.

Comment: I haven't worked with dropwizard for a while now, so I can't confirm, but I guess it's strange this answer is accepted and downvoted at the same time ... maybe someone with more insight can come up with a new answer?